# Angular iframe with auth header. Unsafe url somewhere else?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, iframe

I want to display an iframe but it need an auth header to be accessable. After looking around for a while the only option I have found is to get the data of the website per http get request within the code and add the auth header there and use the blob from the request and set it as `src` of the iframe. This is the code I did use so far:

service.ts:

```
async getIFrameData(url: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            this.http.get(url, {responseType : 'blob'}).subscribe({
                next: (value) => {
                    res(URL.createObjectURL(value))
                },
                error: async (err) => {
                    console.log("ERROR: ", err);
                    rej();
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

component.ts:

```
private setIFrameUrl() {
     this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(await this.service.getIFrameData(this.unsafeUrl));
}
```

component.html:

```
<iframe [src]="safeUrl" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

The http request gets intercepted and will have an auth header added to it so this part does work. The problem I face is that I still get error messages saying that an url is unsafe to use. What I dont understand is that the place where this error message is thrown is not where the iframe is but in another function that calls my backend via `http.get` in the service.ts. When commend out or removing the iframe the error messages disapears and the other functions are working fine. I tryed to also use `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` for the url within the `http.get` function that calls my backend but that doesnt work because the `http.get` only wants a string and not a safe url.

Do you guys have any idea why angular says the other functions are not safe anymore when I use the iframe somewhere else? Also so website from the iframe doesn't seem to load right. It does somehow work but it seems that the site cant load resources properly.

I know that the url is right because when removing the requirement of authorisation on the website I want to access and just give the iframe the `unsafeUrl` the site will load correctly.